# How do I find likelihood for discrete data?

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian, maximum-likelihood

City buses are numbered sequentially 1, 2, ..., M. If M were known, and Y represents the number on the next bus you see, find an expression for P(Y = y|M).

I think that P(Y = y|M) = $\frac{1}{M}$ since for y = 1, 2, ..., M. Is this correct?
I think that this is true because we know that there are M total buses, so the probability that the next bus you see has a specific number on it is one over the total number of buses.

Comment: I think it is $\frac{1}{M-1}$, because it is impossible to see $M$-labeled bus consecutively, or, is it possible?

Comment: Idea is right, but you want the word 'probability' here, not 'likelihood', which has a special technical meaning. For background info, google `German tank problem`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the next bus you see is entirely random, then yes. $P(Y=y|M)=\frac{1}{M}$. If the buses are not entirely random, you need more information to determine the actual probability.